# How to iterate through the rows of the database with [] to an expression of typ 'object' c# mysql

Tags: c#, mysql, object, indexing

How to iterate through the rows of the database, he gave me some example code, but i encounter this problem. `Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'`. What does this mean?

```
foreach (var row in employee.tbl.Rows)
                        {
                            if (row["fStatus"].ToString().Equals("Borrowed"))
                            {
                                txtTITLE_R.Text = row["fBookTitle"].ToString();
                                txtIDNO.Text = row["fIDStudent"].ToString();
                                txtLEVEL.Text = row["fLevel"].ToString();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                MessageBox.Show("Thank you.");
                            }
                        }
```

Comment: my `row` doesn't have any data type also my `employee.tbl.Rows`

Comment: `row` most certainly does have a data type; you have to find out what it is. If you told us where `employee.tbl.Rows` comes from we might be able to help.

Comment: oh sorry it's a `DataTable` my `employee.tbl.Rows`

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that `tbl` is a [DataTable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable(v=vs.110).aspx).  If so, you need to use `DataRow` to access the type-specific members, like this:

```
foreach (DataRow row in employee.tbl.Rows)
{
    //etc....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error is trying to tell you, `row` is declared `object`, which has no indexing operator.

Change `var` to the actual type of the row.

Comment: the original code in there was a actual type of row that i set it's index to `[0]`, like this `cfgotcall.tbl.Rows[0]["fStatus"].ToString().Equals("Borrowed")` this code doesn't read the whole rows of my table, that's why i use `foreach`

Comment: @user3415509: The problem is that whatever `.Rows` is doesn't implement `IEnumerable<T>`, so `var` can't tell what type to use.